# Randomize Background Video with Sound, after clicking function

Tags: javascript, html, video, background, escaping

I wrote this code a while back, and it allowed users to click and refresh the page to autoplay a RANDOM background video with sound.

This is the function that they click that loads the function

https://pastebin.com/0XXEHvQQ

```
    <div align="center"> 
  

  

      <p><font face="verdana" size="2"> 
        <a onclick="ok()"> press me PLAY VIDS :)</a></font></p>
    </div>
```

https://pastebin.com/PD5qdNDM

```
<div align="center"> 
  <p><font face="verdana" size="2"> 
    <a onclick="ok()"> -&gt; press me to fix the site :) &lt;-</a></font></p>
</div>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    
</div>


    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="js/parallax.js"></script>
    <script>

    // Pretty simple huh?
    var scene = document.getElementById('scene');
    var parallax = new Parallax(scene);

</script>

</script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>

<script>

let volumeInterval;

function loaded(){
    
    setInterval(loop, 600);
    volumeInterval = setInterval(volume, 1);
}

function unload(){

    for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++)
        window.clearInterval(i);
    console.log("unloaded");
}

 function volume() {
            try {
                document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].volume = 0.15;
                console.log("done!");
                clearInterval(volumeInterval);
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log("waiting..");
            }
}


function ok() {
    

    document.write(unescape(
```

and heres the unescaped code

```
https://pastebin.com/YJwbG2mC

<!-- VIDEO GRABBB -->
<video preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="true">
<source id="player" src="5.mp4">

    <script>
        var video = document.currentScript.parentElement;
        video.volume = 0.33;
        //document.getElementById('player').currentTime = 20; 

    </script>

        <script>
            var video = document.getElementById("player");
            video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
            if(this.currentTime >= 1000) {
            location.reload();
                }
            });
        </script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

        video.onended = function() {
          location.reload();
        };
    </script>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("player").src = "/" + Math.floor((Math.random()*7)+1) + ".mp4";
    </script>
</video>
```

No matter how I try to adjust the unescaped code, I can't get the MP4 to autoplay after clicking the function.

Here is my live site that I no longer can access: [form.wtf](https://form.wtf/)

Comment: Read this https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#:~:text=Chrome's%20autoplay%20policies%20are%20simple,with%20sound%20is%20allowed%20if%3A&text=On%20desktop%2C%20the%20user's%20Media,previously%20played%20video%20with%20sound.

Comment: yes i understand that, by using
```function ok() {
    

    document.write(unescape(```

I can let the user click the page and let him reload it, I was just curious on how i can implement simple javascript to choose an MP4 file to play as the background.

```<video preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="true">
<source id="player" src="5.mp4">

 <script>
    document.getElementById("player").src = "/" + Math.floor((Math.random()*7)+1) + ".mp4";
    </script>```

I cant remember how to reimpliment that code to add to the src for the mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the HTML Spec on the [Source Element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-source-element),

> Dynamically modifying a source element and its attribute when the element is already inserted in a video or audio element will have no effect. To change what is playing, just use the src attribute on the media element directly, possibly making use of the canPlayType() method to pick from amongst available resources. Generally, manipulating source elements manually after the document has been parsed is an unnecessarily complicated approach.

Therefore, no matter what you do to the `source` element, you can't change the `video` unless the new `src` is applied directly to the `video` element.

Replacing the `source` element also has no effect on the `video` that plays. The `source` element's `src` attribute may changed but the video will keep on playing.

Therefore, you should leave your `source's` `src` attribute empty until the JavaScript code sets it or

Leave out the `source` tag all together and apply the `src` straight to the video.

`Math.floor(Math.random() * 7 + 1);` is exactly the same thing as `Math.ceil(Math.random() * 7);`

```
document.querySelector('#player > source').src = `/${Math.ceil(Math.random() * 7)}.mp4`;

<video id="player" preload="auto" autoplay loop> 
  <source src="">
</video>
```

Comment: That its, thank you! Appreciate the time you spent, I got it working now.